# Use of unresolved identifier 'AVAsset'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchkit

I have tried so many things and I also have looked through the internet but I could not find a way to resolve the following issue. 
Xcode shows me this error:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'AVAsset'
```

even though I have imported AVFoundation and also have imported the framework AVFoundation via Build phase.

Here is the picture of the error:

[image: error]

[Here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=38128676605242153939) is my code.

The main code is in the *InterfaceController.swift* file

I hope that someone can help me out. 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AVAsset from AVFoundation framework is not supported by WatchOS SDK. 
You should use [WKAudioFileAsset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkaudiofileasset)

Comment: Thank you very much. This part works now. But, if you want to retrieve the audio file from the document directory path, you need to create a WKAudioFileAsset is this correct? 
The audio file would be the FileAsset, is that right?

Comment: you mean the document directory path of the watch os app or ios app?

Comment: @ Do both have a document directory?? I have thought just the iphone has a document directory. 
But getting the AVAsset/WKAudioFileAsset is the .wav file? Is WKAudioFileAsset the retrieved audio file, since I need to send the whole recorded audio file to the server. I hope you can help me out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56308275/getting-the-audio-file-from-the-document-directory 
here are more details :) thank you very much. I can see you are also from Germany :)

Comment: never assume what other conversation partner could know or not – that's why I tried to clarify :) so according to documentation the file should be on local file system

Comment: But is the WKAudioFileAsset actually the .wav file? I have looked through the whole internet about retrieving the audio file from the document directory and that's just what I have found, namely via the AVAsset in terms of the iphone.
How is it possible to access the local file system, since everything is hidden and sandboxed in apple :(

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial about audio recording in watch os: https://www.raywenderlich.com/345-audio-recording-in-watchos-tutorial

Comment: Thank you very much. I think the asset is the audio file. Do you think it is possible to send the asset to the server? Since at the server side we want to process the audio file.

Comment: The server cannot do something with the NSData, which is the binary data.